# How to store user input in txt file?

Tags: shell

i have to store user input in two file . if user input mango then it should be automatically stored in grocery file or if user input shirt then it should be stored in clothe file and finally merge  both files in one file.
what i have done so far is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
touch grocry.txt clothes.txt other.txt

echo -n "enter a item: "
read item
if 
  grep -Fxq "$item" item1.txt
then
  echo -n "$item" >> grocry.txt
elif -Fxq "$item" item2.txt
then
  echo -n "$item" >> clothes.txt
else
  echo -n "$item" >> other.txt
fi
```

Comment: It is unclear what your desired output is and it seems you did little research on the issue. What are `item1.txt` and `item2.txt`?

Comment: item1.txt and item2.txt is a file where  data is pre-stored.In item1.txt there is grocery item and in item2.txt clothe item name. And i want to match user input  with file data ,if match is found then it would be stored in given file accordingly.

Comment: Is there just one item name in each file? Or is the program supposed to loop through a list of items in the file to see if it matches any of them?

Comment: there is list of items in each file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
touch grocery.txt clothes.txt other.txt

read -rp "Enter an item: " item

if grep -wq "$item" item1.txt; then
    echo "$item" >> grocery.txt
elif grep -wq "$item" item2.txt; then
    echo "$item" >> clothes.txt
else
    echo "$item" >> other.txt
fi
```

`read` has a built-in prompt capability and you were missing the grep on one of the conditional lines.

Comment: yes,but it's not working.You got my question or not.

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically is not working? I have tested the above method and it seems to work.

Comment: each user input getting stored in other.txt

Comment: You need to post an example of the contents of `item1.txt` and `item2.txt`. Are the items in those files separated by a comma, tab, newline? The above code works if the items are each on their own line without surrounding whitespace.

Comment: contents in a file is column-wise

Comment: Bananas
 Berries
 Grapes
 Lemons
 Lime
 Melons
 Nectarines
 Oranges

Comment: I changed the `grep` flag to avoid using the `-Fx` which told `grep` to only search on lines. It should work appropriately now. Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the time to provide as much detail as possible when asking questions in the future.